# Java dates period compare

Tags: java, date, vector, comparison

I would like to create a function in java that would do the following:

1. Get a list of Objects in a vector with fields `startDate`, `endDate`
2. Get a second list of Objects in a vector with fields `startDate`, `endDate`
   and return `true` or `false` if for each date period from the first list (`startDate` to `endDate`) , there is a corresponding date period in the second list.

However, the date period in the second list could be filled by consecutive dates.
For example List1 (with only one object): `Object1` (Start date = 01/01/2010 , End date = 01/01/2013)

If provided with List2 (2 objects) : `Object1` (Start date = 01/01/2010, End date = 01/03/2010) `Object2` (Start date = 01/03/2010 End date = 01/01/2013)
should return `true`

Comment: Ok, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Start by googling with these key words java+calendar+date comparison. Then come back and let us know how far you have progressed.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some pseudo code for you...

1. Create a third list of start/end dates
2. For each start/end in second list

   - If overlaps with any existing date-span in the third list, extend that date-span
   - otherwise just add it to the third list
3. For each start/end *(a, b)* in the first list

   1. Set *covered* = false
   2. For each start/end *(c, d)* in third list
   3. If *(c,d)* covers *(a, b)*

      - Set *covered* = true
   4. If not covered, return false
4. Return true

To figure out the "overlap" part above you need to cover the following cases:

```
|-----|
  |-|
```

```
  |-----|
|---|
```

```
|-----|
    |---|
```

```
  |-|
|-----|
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert all dates to [millis since epoch](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) and the intersection of the ranges becomes trivial.

Comment: That only simplifies the date-comparison, but that's trivial with Dates too.